# How to read a SQL file with python with proper character encoding?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Based on a few examples ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261061/execute-sql-schema-in-psycopg2-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416405/use-python-and-psycopg2-to-execute-a-sql-file-that-contains-a-drop-database-stat)) I can use psycopg2 to read and hopefully run a SQL file from python (the file is 200 lines, and though runs quickly, isn't something I want to maintain in a python file).

Here is the script to read and run the file:

```
sql = open("sql/sm_bounds_current.sql", "r").read()

curDest.execute(sql)
```

However, when I run the script, the following error is thrown:

```
Error: syntax error at or near "ï»¿drop"
LINE 1: ï»¿drop table dpsdata.sm_boundaries_current_dev;
```

As you can see, the first line in the script is to drop a table, but I'm not sure why the extra characters are being read, and can't seem to find a solution that might set the encoding of the file when reading it.

Comment: 10:1 that file has been corrupted by a dodgy text editor.  "utf8: BOM considered harmful"

Comment: @Jasen hmm, I was just using PGAdmin3 - I'll see if I can check any other reader/writer for a better method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294156/1704448) dealing with encoding and byte order marks, which is where my problem was.

The solution was to import OPEN from CODECS, which allows for the ENCODING option on OPEN:

```
import codecs
from codecs import open

sqlfile = "sql/sm_bounds_current.sql"
sql = open(sqlfile, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
curDest.execute(sql)
```

Seems to work great!

Comment: Oh wow ... thank you! I had a similar issue, and forcing the encoding to utf-8 seemed to do the trick for me too, even though the file is already utf-8 unicode.

Comment: @ray_voelker great!!

Comment: Nice :) This also did the trick for me! Ps: It works already without the `import codecs` -part, so you can choose to take that out if you want :)

Comment: I used encoding="utf-8" and errors='ignore' to read sql files generated by ssms